# Xposed Framework

Tags: xposed-framework

What framework is better to put on this device?
build.prop file

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=V417IR
ro.build.display.id=V417IR release-keys
ro.build.version.incremental=eng.root.20191017.113722
ro.build.version.sdk=23
ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
ro.build.version.release=6.0.1
ro.build.version.security_patch=2017-02-01
ro.build.version.base_os=
ro.build.date=Thu Oct 17 11:39:08 UTC 2019
ro.build.date.utc=1571312348
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=root
ro.build.host=f1c1db3625fe
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.build.flavor=cancro_x64-user
ro.bootloader=U-Boot
ro.bootmode=normal
ro.baseband=msm
ro.product.model=MuMu
ro.product.brand=Android
ro.product.name=cancro_x64
ro.product.device=x86_64
ro.product.board=
# ro.product.cpu.abi and ro.product.cpu.abi2 are obsolete,
# use ro.product.cpu.abilist instead.
ro.product.cpu.abi=x86_64
ro.product.cpu.abilist=x86_64,x86,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=x86_64,arm64-v8a
ro.product.manufacturer=Netease
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=x86_64
# Do not try to parse description, fingerprint, or thumbprint
ro.build.description=cancro_x64-user 6.0.1 V417IR eng.root.20191017.113722 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=OnePlus/OnePlus2/OnePlus2:6.0.1/MMB29M/1447841200:user/release-keys
ro.build.characteristics=tablet
# end build properties
#
# from device/generic/x86_64/system.prop
#
# system.prop for lollipop-x86
#poweroff.doubleclick=1

ro.sf.lcd_density=240
qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
debug.sf.nobootanimation=1

ro.kernel.android.checkjni=0
dalvik.vm.checkjni=false

ro.product.locale=zh-CN
persist.sys.timezone=Asia/Shanghai

ro.build.version.x64=true

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
ro.ril.hsxpa=1
ro.ril.gprsclass=10
keyguard.no_require_sim=true
ro.com.android.dataroaming=true
dalvik.vm.heapstartsize=8m
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=192m
dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m
dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization=0.75
dalvik.vm.heapminfree=512k
dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree=8m
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm=x86
ro.enable.native.bridge.exec=1
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm64=x86_64
ro.enable.native.bridge.exec64=1
ro.carrier=unknown
ro.config.notification_sound=FadeIn.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=Alarm_Classic.ogg
persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2=libart
dalvik.vm.isa.x86_64.variant=x86_64
dalvik.vm.isa.x86_64.features=default
dalvik.vm.isa.x86.variant=dalvik.vm.isa.x86.features=default
ro.kernel.android.checkjni=0
dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold=500
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-filter=verify-at-runtime
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-filter=verify-at-runtime
dalvik.vm.usejit=true
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
```

xposed-v86.1-sdk23-arm64-systemless-by-romracer-20160928 not work
xposed-v86-sdk23-arm64 not work

xposed-v85-sdk23-x86_64-MIUI-edition-by-SolarWarez-20160610 work

But after activating any module in Xposed, the device does not load

Comment: Did you try the rovo version? https://dl-xda.xposed.info/framework/

Comment: Hi
I tried
x86 writes that there is no lib86 folder
arm 64 device does not boot.
Here is the error screen https://cloud.mail.ru/public/sFEV/4JyZ2iEyQ

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that